# PHP JSON encode without []

Tags: php, json

I have this code:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT UPPER(zanr) FROM zanrovi ORDER BY id ASC");
echo json_encode(array('section' => $result->fetch_all()));
```

I get this JSON from above query:

```
{"section":[["AAA"],["BBB"],["CCC"],["DDD"]]}
```

And i need to get this:

```
{"section":["AAA","BBB","CCC","DDD"]}
```

So i could not figure out what i have done false in PHP to return [ and ]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with [`array_column()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

```
echo json_encode(array('section' => array_column($result->fetch_all(), 0)));
```

You can also achieve this with `foreach(){}` or `array_map()` but `array_column()` basically loops the array for you and only returns items whose key match the second parameter.

Comment: Thanks..works very well...and smart answer...i will bookmark this answer for my future project.

Comment: There's also `PDO::FETCH_NUM` and `PDO::FETCH_NAMED`. http://us3.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: @Sammitch OP seems to be using MySQLi. Is there an equivalent?

Comment: Oops. Uhhh... *not* using mysqli? :3c